# Is there a way to change blenders rename character limit?

Tags: data-blocks, settings

I, just tried to rename a Blender timeline marker to a longer sentence and noticed there's a limit of 63 characters. So I was wondering if there was a way to change this limit.

Comment: Not unless you get the source code, make some changes and make your own build.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It's not that important anyway.